# Elasticsearch, multi_match, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I'm would like to use ElasticSearch to search my collection of products.

If I have a object like this:

```
{ name: "Product Name", producer: "Best Producer"}
```

I would like to find this object by searching for:

1. product
2. bes
3. pro
4. name
5. producer
6. best produc
7. best nam

etc.

This code works good, but for example "name" isn't prefix:

```
Product.search(
  {
    multi_match: {
      query: params[:search_input],
      type: "phrase_prefix",
      fields: ["name", "producer"],
      operator: "and"
    }
  })
```

How to improve it?

Comment: Can you show your mapping? use sth like this to get it: http://localhost:9200/indexName/_mapping/typeName/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.

I managed to solve the problem.
This is my solution:

```
Product.search(
  {
    multi_match: {
      query: params[:search_input],
      type: "best_fields",
      fields: ["name", "producer"],
      operator: "and"
    }
  }
)
```

My mapping looks like this:

```
mapping do
  indexes :name, type: :string, search_analyzer: :str_search_analyzer, index_analyzer: :str_index_analyzer
  indexes :producer, type: :string, search_analyzer: :str_search_analyzer, index_analyzer: :str_index_analyzer
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bool,should and term for your multimatch parameters.

```
       Product.search(:query => @query)

       @query = {
          :bool => {
              :must => @must_queries
          }
       }

       :bool => {
            :should => [
                {
                    :terms => {
                        :your_mathcing_field_name => value
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

You can put multiple terms for your each field.